How to listen to newly created drawers in org-mode
I am trying to put some overlays over org-mode drawers and can easily parse the buffer with the element api and attach my desired overlays at place.
For editing live, I struggle with respect to two use-cases:

When inserting, moving, refiling sections
When typing drawer keywords, i.e. creating a new drawer

For both cases parsing the whole buffer again, seems like an overkill. In addition one has to detect that the event shas occured.
Alternativley, I've tried to listen to various functions, e.g. org-mode-element-parser, but this function is executed rather often and potentially also over the whole file, re-reading any drawer in the buffer. This also appears to be a rather expensive approach.
Is there something lighter available?
I am on emacs 29.2 with latest stable org-mode.
